# Swift code nested If statement is very slow?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code that looks like this:

```
var fullJSON = "["

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Job")

do {
    if let jobs = try coreDataContext().fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Job] {
        
        // let jobs: [Job] = fetchCoreData(entity: "Job")
        for job in jobs {
            if let json = job.toJSON() {
                
                
               /*if (fullJSON.count > 1) {
                   
                   //print( "size of values is : \(fullJSON)" )
                   
                    //fullJSON += ",\n "
                }*/
                fullJSON += json
                
                //print( "size of values is : \(fullJSON)" )
            } else {
                print("COULDN'T JSON \(job.name ?? "")")
                callback("Error decoding \(job.name ?? "")")
                return
            }
        }
        
        fullJSON += "]"
        
        API.sync(json: fullJSON) { (result) in
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if !result.success {
                    callback("Network error: " + result.error)
                    return
                }
                guard let jsonJobs = result.payload?["jobs"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
                    callback("Error parsing result"); return
                }
                
                //delete existing
                let existing: [Job] = self.fetchCoreData(entity: "Job")
                for item in existing {
                    self.coreDataContext().delete(item)
                }
                for job in jsonJobs {
                    let newJob = Job.init(context: self.coreDataContext())
                    newJob.load(job, context: self.coreDataContext())
                }
                
                
                try? self.coreDataContext().save()
                callback(nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        callback("Error getting jobs")
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it is very slow!

I've pin pointed the issue to this code:

```
if (fullJSON.count > 1) {
    fullJSON += ",\n "
}
```

If I remove that code, everything is fast again!

I have no idea why that small part of the code makes everything so slow!

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: What is `job`? What is `toJSON()`? What is `fullJSON`?

Comment: @vadian, please view my edit. hopefully that will shed more light on everything.

Comment: If you make your Job class conform to `Encodable` then you could skip much of the code and do `let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(jobs)` and make a string from `data`

Comment: I agree with Joakim. Adopt `Encodable` in your Core Data class and implement `encode(to: Encoder)`. This is more efficient than manually putting together the string. By the way, JSON doesn't need to be *pretty printed* by linefeed characters. The server doesn't care.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, this is not my code. its something thats assigned to me to fix!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Valid comments regarding better approaches to your task, however...

Pretty certain the speed difference is in the use of:

```
if (fullJSON.count > 1) {
```

that `.count` is a very expensive operation.

Try adding this to a view controller. Each time you tap anywhere, we'll simulate your json activity by appending "ABC" to the string var.

The first loop uses your `fullJSON.count` to decide to add the ",\n"

The second loop uses a Bool variable to append the ",\n" only after the first time through.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    var fullJSON: String = ""
    
    var length1: Int = 0
    var length2: Int = 0

    var st1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    var st2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    var ed1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    var ed2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    st1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    fullJSON = "["
    for _ in 1...5000 {
        if fullJSON.count > 1 {
            fullJSON += ",\n"
        }
        fullJSON += "ABC"
    }
    ed1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    length1 = fullJSON.count
    
    var b: Bool = false
    
    st2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    fullJSON = "["
    for _ in 1...5000 {
        if b {
            fullJSON += ",\n"
        }
        fullJSON += "ABC"
        // we've gone through once
        b = true
    }
    ed2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    
    length2 = fullJSON.count
    
    print("Timing:", ed1 - st1, ed2 - st2)
    
    // to confirm we get same resulting string lengths
    print("Lengths:", length1, length2)
    
    print()
}
```

Here's what I get on 5 runs:

```
Timing: 0.5321569442749023 0.002187013626098633
Lengths: 24999 24999

Timing: 0.5368150472640991 0.0024269819259643555
Lengths: 24999 24999

Timing: 0.5297999382019043 0.002218961715698242
Lengths: 24999 24999

Timing: 0.5305029153823853 0.002167940139770508
Lengths: 24999 24999

Timing: 0.5307689905166626 0.0022219419479370117
Lengths: 24999 24999
```

This is, of course, not the ideal way to profile code, but we can easily see the big difference here.

Comment: and yes, the issue is this: if (fullJSON.count > 1) {

Comment: also, if you look at the code in the question, there's a closing bracket at the end of the code and you don't have that! at what point should that bracket should be used in your code?!

Comment: @drago - I was simply showing the line with the problem. If you look at (and run) the sample code in my answer, you'll see that both `if` statements have closing brackets.